# Non-convex Constraint Satisfaction problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gradient-descent, non-convex-optimization

I am not an expert on constrained optimization problems so I was wondering whether some of you could help me out.

Let $h_{\mu}$ stand for :

\begin{equation}
h_{\mu} (\vec{X}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \vec{X} \cdot \vec{\xi}_{\mu} - \sigma
\end{equation}

Here $\vec{X}$ and $\vec{\xi}_{\mu}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ with $\mu = 1..M$. Thus $\xi_{\mu}^{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$. $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}$ (can be negative)

I then define a constraint satisfaction problem to be the determination of all $\vec{X}$ such that $\forall \mu$ for given $\vec{\xi}_{\mu}$, we have

\begin{equation}
h_{\mu}(\vec{X}) > 0
\end{equation}

The $\vec{\xi}_{\mu}$ are taken from a gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $\sigma$ is kept fixed. 
There are some constraints on $\vec{X}$:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_{i} = m \\
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} X_{i}^2 =1 
\end{align}

I define a cost function of the following form:

\begin{equation}
\text{H}[\vec{X}] = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{\mu = 1}^{M} \Big( \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\vec{X} \cdot \vec{\xi}_{\mu} - \sigma \Big)^{2}  \theta(-h_{\mu})
\end{equation}

In other words, I incur a cost only $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\vec{X} \cdot \vec{\xi}_{\mu} - \sigma < 0$, i.e. whenever $h_{\mu} <0$.

The optimisation problem then is to minimize the cost function $\text{H}$ subject to the two constraints on $\vec{X}$. The other variables $\vec{\xi}_{\mu}$ and $\sigma$ are given and kept fixed.

My questions are :

1. Is there a specific name for these types of optimisation problems?
2. Are there analytical ways to treat such problems?

My attempt at computing the minimum of $\text{H}$ has essentially involved writing my own gradient descent routine which, as you may imagine, is not extremely performant leading to very long waiting times to find the solution.  I wondered whether such problems have already been studied in the literature, so that I could use some existing knowledge to do this problem.

Thanks for your help. Cheers.

Comment: Is everything other than $\vec{X}$ an input to the optimization problem, i.e., fixed?  It might help if you write out the cost (a.k.a. objective) function explicitly in terms of $\vec{X}$. I have no idea what the  cost function is.

Comment: Yes everything else is fixed. I shall update the question as you suggested.

Comment: Your notation is very non-standard, to put it mildly. 
So $\text{H}[\vec{X}] = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{\mu = 1}^{M} \text{max}(\Big( \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\vec{X} \cdot \vec{\xi}_{\mu} - \sigma \Big),0)^2
$? And are there M different $\vec{\xi}_{\mu}$ and they are drawn once, and always the same M values used?Are you constraining $h_{\mu}(\vec{X}) > 0$
 for these same M values of $\vec{\xi}_{\mu}$? By then wouldn't the objective function be zero for all feasible $\vec{X}$, in which case you just want to find a feasible $\vec{X}$, and there is nothing really to optimize? This is still very confusing.

Comment: I apologise for the notation. The problem is to find the $\vec{X}$ such that for a given choice of $\vec{\xi}_{\mu}$, we minimize the objective function $\text{H}$. Minimizing this objective function is equivalent to minimizing the number of  unsatisfied constraints $h_{\mu}$.

And you are right that the objective function would be zero for the feasible $\vec{X}$, but then I am not guaranteed that I can always find such an $\vec{X}$. That would depend on $M$ and $N$ (their ratio) right?

Comment: If you are willing to accept a solution which doesn't meet all constraints, then don;t make them constraints - handle them in the objective function.